# Rails limiting the query to a number of results

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

i want to create a set of querys, the first finds all records that are created after a specific date and then the second one displays all the records that are created before that date. Since there are 30,000 records i would like to only show 10 that are closest to the date that i set.

```
 private
def current_scorecards_for_review
  self.where("created_at > ? AND reviewed = ?", Date.new(2013,04,01), false)
end

def historic_scorecards_for_review
  self.where("created_at < ? AND reviewed = ?", Date.new(2013,04,01), false).limit(10)
end
```

thats what i have written so far, when i tried it in the console

```
e = Scorecard.where("created_at < ?", Date.new(2013,04,01)).limit(10)
```

and then called

```
e.count
```

it will return => 30175, how do i make it so that only 10 will be returned? and with there being 30,000 rows this is slow.

Comment: it's weird that you're getting the total count.  i just tried this out and it returns 10.

Comment: just tried again still returning 30175.. irb(main):015:0> e = Scorecard.where("created_at < ?", Date.new(2013,04,01)).limit(10)

e.count
=> 30175

Comment: can you add a `to_a` at the end?

Comment: its returning 10, which is great just wondering now why its still returning the total when calling .count or .size, thanks for the help btw

Comment: count is an active record method, I think you're confusing it with length()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `count` on an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) object will trigger a count query.  SQL limits don't work as you are expecting with count queries, since the limit will actually be applied to the resulting count itself - which is typically a single row (unless using GROUP BY):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM scorecards 
WHERE created_at < '2013-04-01' AND reviewed = false 
LIMIT 10
```

When you call `to_a` (or `all` or anything else that actually triggers the query), you are working on the returned collection - `count` will now return the length of the collection.

See [`here`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyonrails-core/zWM_s3mOrQo) for a discussion about this.